# iCloud - renaming open documents on another device sometimes fails

Tags: ios, iphone, icloud, renaming

The issue: I'm working on an iCloud document on device A, e.g. iPod Touch. Then I change the name of the document on device B, e.g. my Mac (via the Finder). The change goes up to the cloud and after a pause device A gets to hear about it.

And then:

- some of the time all is just fine - I pick up the change of name via a changed `fileURL` property and can update my interface accordingly - the document continues to behave just as it should
- some of the time, the document's fileURL is returned as something such as: `file://localhost/var/mobile/Library/Mobile%20Documents/.ubd/peer-43A0AEB6-84CE-283E-CA39-FCC4EF3BC8F8-v23/ftr/purg-012fdcfbe3b3bbce6e603fdfd2f000b2cb28649e95` Not surprisingly this file won't save.

Can anyone explain what is going on and how to work around it?

**Background**

- The name change is picked up fine by by `NSMetadataQuery`. So, for e.g., I can rename documents that are not open and all my iCloud functionality works fine. The issue only seems to occur with open documents.
- Other iCloud features are working fine, e.g. I can change content on one device, e.g. my Mac,  and detect and then update my interface on another device, e.g. my iPod Touch, that has the relevant iCloud document open.
- I first spotted this when I added an override for `presentedItemDidMoveToURL:` to my UIDocument subclass. The override reliably picks up name changes made in the cloud, e.g. renaming the document on another device. Then *sometimes* newURL is the final expected URL for the renamed document, i.e. something sensible from which I can extract the new name use `lastPathComponent', update my interface etc. On other occasions newURL is a document in some other directory with a last path component beginning 'purg-', e.g. purg-012fdcfbe3b3bbce6e603fdfd2f000b2cb28649e95.

  ```
  - (void) presentedItemDidMoveToURL:(NSURL *) newURL;
  {   
      [super presentedItemDidMoveToURL: newURL];

      if ([(id)[self delegate] respondsToSelector:@selector(documentNameChanged:)])
      {
          [[self delegate] documentNameChanged: self];
      }
  }
  ```
- The `presentedItemDidMoveToURL:` method does not seem to be the root cause of the problem. For example, if I don't override that method at all, but periodically check in the viewController that is looking after the open document, then *sometimes* after a rename `fileURL` will return the new name and *sometimes* it will return `purg-.....'. So the issue appears to be to do with how renaming is handled.

**Update**

As al_lea pointed out, the issue here was related to `accommodatePresentedItemDeletionWithCompletionHandler:`. Expanding on al_lea's answer, I added the code below to my UIDocument subclass. This fixed the issue.

```
    - (void) accommodatePresentedItemDeletionWithCompletionHandler: (void (^) (NSError *errorOrNil)) completionHandler
    {    
        PresentedDocument* presentedDocument = [self retain];
        [presentedDocument closeWithCompletionHandler: ^(BOOL success) {        
            NSError* error = nil;
            if (!success)
            {
                NSDictionary* userInfo = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                    @"Could not close document that is being deleted on another device",
                    NSLocalizedDescriptionKey, nil];
                    error = [NSError errorWithDomain: @"some_suitable_domain"
                                                code: 101
                                           userInfo: userInfo];
            }

        completionHandler(error);  // run the passed in completion handler (required)

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^
        {
           [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName: NOTIFY_presentedDocumentDeletedOnAnotherDevice
                                                               object: presentedDocument
                                                             userInfo: nil];

           [presentedDocument tidyUpAfterDelete];  // app specific tidy up
           [presentedDocument release];
       });
    }];
}
```

With this code in place, there are no spurious and confusing presentedItemDidMoveToURL: calls made and, in addition, the relevant object can listen for notifications of deletions on other devices.

Comment: I tried to make iCloud work using just DocumentState for around a month- this was the piece I was missing. 

Prior to adding this code items would sometimes return after deletion, or I would get a continuous stream of continually changing document states

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This type of URL appears when a UIDocument is opened on local and get deleted from a remote device:

`file://localhost/var/mobile/Library/Mobile%20Documents/.ubd/peer-43A0AEB6-84CE-283E-CA39-FCC4EF3BC8F8-v23/ftr/purg-`

You need to close the document first before it get deleted - detect this in NSFilePresenter's `accommodatePresentedItemDeletionWithCompletionHandler:`