# Deleted UIDocument often reappears from cloud

Tags: icloud

I'm working with documents in the cloud...
* Add a document to the cloud
* Delete that document from the cloud
* Somehow that document reappears a few seconds later.

Here's the details:

I create an instance of UIDocument like this

```
    NSURL *ubiq = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier:nil];
    NSURL *ubiquitousPackage = [[ubiq URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"somenewfilename"];

    MyDoc* docTemp = [[MyDoc alloc] initWithFileURL:ubiquitousPackage];
    docTemp.mapContent = [NSString stringWithString:self.currentdocument.mapContent];

    [docTemp saveToURL:[docTemp fileURL] 
      forSaveOperation:UIDocumentSaveForCreating 
     completionHandler:^(BOOL success) {            
         if (success) {
             DLog(@"New document %@ saved/added: %@", newFilename, docTemp);
         }
         else {
             DLog(@"Failed saving new document: %@", newFilename);
         }
         [docTemp release];
     }];
```

Then delete it later like this:

```
    NSURL* fileURL = self.currentdocument.fileURL;
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^(void)       {
    NSFileCoordinator* fileCoordinator = [[NSFileCoordinator alloc] initWithFilePresenter:nil];
    NSError* error = nil;
    [fileCoordinator coordinateWritingItemAtURL:fileURL options:NSFileCoordinatorWritingForDeleting error:&error byAccessor:^(NSURL* writingURL) {
        if (error != nil) {
            DLog(@"Error with %@! %@", fileURL, error);
            return;
        }
        DLog(@"Got writingURL: %@", writingURL);
        NSFileManager* fileManager = [[NSFileManager alloc] init];
        if ([fileManager removeItemAtURL:writingURL error:nil]) {
            DLog(@"Deleted %@!", writingURL);
        }
        else {
            DLog(@"ERROR Failed deleting %@!", self.currentdocument);
        }
        [fileManager release];
        [fileCoordinator release];
    }];
});
```

Now despite doing the above, it looks like the file is deleted for a (short) while, but on several occasions the deleted document reappears in the cloud one or a few seconds later. (I can check this through iCloud settings on another device, or through a query that sends notifications on updates). Only on SOME occasions the file remains deleted. What's going on?

I should note that even deleting the file from Settings->iCloud will cause the above pattern. The file magically reappears a few seconds later. Timing issues? Sync issues?

Comment: Did you find out how to resolve this?

Comment: I think my problem was that I always kept all docs in my list (I have an interface with all docs in the cloud...) open. Ahh, long story short you're not supposed to keep files open unless you open them in a kind of editor interface or similar. As long as a doc is open, I guess it wouldn't make sense to delete it. I changed my app to only open docs when the user taps on them. I think this fixed my problem.

Comment: okay, thanks, that might help me work out why my documents arent deallocating! maybe I need to close them :)

Comment: Yes it would make sense because if that same document is open on a device A and you try to delete it on a device B, nothing bad would happen to the app on device A and the doc would still remain in cloud.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Don't delete documents while they are open. :-P

Comment: God dammit, I lost a cumulated 20 frustrating hours on this. Thanx for clearing that up!

Answer (score 3):

One possible source of problems in this area is that the documentState of your UIDocument passes through these states sequentially on delete...

> 8 (UIDocumentStateEditingDisabled)
>
> then 0 (UIdocumentStateNormal)  probably to update the filename,
>
> then 4 (UIDocumentStateSavingError) to delete.

Therefore the deletion may be fighting against your code that fires when you receive a UIDocumentStateChangedNotification saying that the state is normal.

I hope this helps someone.

UPDATE

Instead of trying to drive everything from DocumentState, as I tried unsuccessfully for a month to do (following Wenderlich examples)...

The key for me was adding **accommodatePresentedItemDeletionWithCompletionHandler** to the subclassed UIDocument, containing a closeWithCompletionhandler: call that closes the open file on all devices as deletion is detected. It then posts a notification to my manager to remove instances of this item from the source data array.

This seems much more robust and predictable. I do still see several DocumentState 8 and State 9s arriving to each device following a deletion, where I would expect to only see one, but that may be a different issue.

Comment: Brilliant!  I, too, had used the Ray Wenderlich tutorial and ran into this problem.  Even though your answer is now 4 years old, adding `accommodatePresentedItemDeletion` still did the trick!  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In my case, "accommodatePresentedItemDeletionWithCompletionHandler:" works to stop once-deleted-files reappearing, by force closing when the UIDocument is unconsciously opened.
You can see the usage of it here: [iCloud - renaming open documents on another device sometimes fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8656504/icloud-renaming-open-documents-on-another-device-sometimes-fails)